# Unit testing LINQ which returns an integer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have this test which verifies if I call the Query() in my reference.

```
[TestFixture]
public class When_retrieving_an_application_license
{
    [Test]
    public void available_licenses_should_be_counted()
    {
        // Arrange
        var sut = new LicenseManager();
        var mockILicenseRepository = new Mock<ILicenseRepository>();
        sut.LicenseRepository = mockILicenseRepository.Object;
        // Act
        sut.GetLicenseCount(Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid());
        // Assert
        mockIApplicationLicenseRepository.Verify(x => x.Query());
    }
}
```

However, the GetLicenseCount(Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid()) function looks like this:

```
 public int GetLicenseCount(Guid cId, Guid appId) 
          => LicenseRepository.Query()
             .Count(al => al.CId == cId && al.AppId == appId 
                                        && al.UserId == null 
                                        && al.Expiry > DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Query() returns all in the repo to count which UserId's are in null.
**Is it enough to say that the test is OK even if it only verifies the query() part of the linq?
How about the count?**

Comment: I prefer to use different tests for different purposes. So if you check if some method or property is called and check if the return value is correct, this should be two tests. I would create a second test, which assert the return value.

Comment: I'd suggest you shouldn't be verifying `Query` is called at all.  Set up your stub repository query to return some values and verify that your method returns the result you would expect for those values. Test the *behaviour*, not how it's implemented.

Comment: I agree with @CharlesMager . It is just waste of time to test the .Query(). Think of it is like a SQL query in you application. Unit Test the domain, behavior in your business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to make sure the right count is being returned you will need to arrange your mocked ILicenseRepository to return the data you are expecting.

```
var mockILicenseRepository = new Mock<ILicenseRepository>();
mockILicenseRepository.Setup(x => x.Query()).Returns(new {CId = guid, AppId = guid2, Expiry = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)};
```

You will also need to store the return value to assert against

```
var actualCount = sut.GetLicenseCount(Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid());
Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, actualCount);
```

However, if you are unit testing LINQ's Query method then I think you may want to restructure your production code because unit testing framework methods is unnecessary.

Comment: It looked like you were using Moq as your mocking framework so my examples are with that syntax (my assert is MsTest not sure what you were using).  Just FYI